# How do I get $view->the actual row number?

Tags: views, theming

How do I get the actual rows number in views-view-field--title.tpl.php in Drupal7 and views3?

I know how to get the total by

```
$view = views_get_current_view();
$view->total_rows;
```

But how do I get the actual row number? To print
1/4
2/4
3/4
4/4

Comment: if you want see another way direct from the view you can check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/178651/28275

Answer (score 13):

user1090003 has the right answer.

> in views-view-fields.tpl.php or... you can have the row index like this $view->row_index

Further explanation:

In views-view-field--title.tpl.php (suggestion of views-view-fields.tpl.php), you already have the $view object available.   That view object has a property "row_index" that equals the current row number starting at zero.

Example of use:

```
    <?php print $view->row_index; ?>
    <?php print $output; ?>
```

Example results:

```
    0
    Node Title 1
    --
    1
    Node Title 2
```

Comment: This also works in a node--view--<my-view>.tpl.php

Answer (score 3):

I usually accomplish this by adding a "count" field and making it excluded from display. In the title field I add the token for the "count" field in "rewrite output." Make sure the count field is BEFORE the title field.

Comment: I use field **Global PHP** as numbering column and there I put `echo ($view->row_index);` works well in Drupal 7 (but counts from ZERO).

Answer (score 2):

in views-view-fields.tpl.php or... you can have the row index like this $view->row_index

Comment: Hello. Could you please explain a bit, and maybe provide code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the $static var to 0 in the VALUE CODE area allows to do $static++ in de OUTPUT CODE area

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a little?

Comment: In views there are two fields when using the Global PHP field. You can set pre and post render data in these. This works just fine for a simple counter.