# How to add an ascending row number (using some token) in front of each row in Views?

Tags: views, tokens

I can't figure out how to make a soccer league table that would look like this: http://prntscr.com/8va7h7

This is how the table looks now: http://prntscr.com/8va8eu

Everything works but I don't know how to show the team position on the table. Is there a way to make this work using tokens so they count the number of rows?

Comment: You have to include a lot more info... for example, how are you creating the table, thru views? which fields are you sorting by etc... what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your View add a new Field, Filter by Global and select:

> **Global: View result counter**
>
> *Displays the actual position of the view result*

Click the *Apply* button and if you want change the output select *Rewrite the output of this field* in the *Rewrite results* section, and in the *Replacement patterns* section you will see the `[counter]` token as:

> [counter] == Global: View result counter